# How do I use the proxy bypass in uplink?

Tags: uplink

I have a proxy bypass (v.5) and have no idea how to use it.

How can I use this tool and are there any gotchas relating to it's use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Down at the left bottom of your screen is the HUD Analyzer (assuming you bought it first). Run that and it will bring up a window that shows the computer and boxes with question marks in them. These question marks will reveal what security this system has (Proxy, Monitor, Firewall).

Now run your bypasser and move that little box over the proper security box (proxy bypass for Proxy, monitor bypass for Monitor, etc). The bypasser box should lock itself to that security system and bypass it for you.

Comment: Don't forget you have to buy the analyzer before you can use bypasses.

Comment: Can the "Connection Analyser" be used in this way?

Comment: Yes it can, but instead you drag it over computer (I think) instead of security systems.